# Lightspeed Retail Cloud API WooCommerce Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, lightspeed

I am doing some digging into how to integrate the LightSpeed Cloud API into WordPress WooCommerce plugin.
http://www.lightspeedretail.com/cloud/help/developers/

I've gained access to my API key and account id and I am using the OAuth class provided by GitHub. Using PHP and Visual Studio, I have successfully been able to pull my inventory records XML data.

Looking ahead, my question(s) are:

1. (Easy way, but most unlikely) Are there any third party WooCommerce Plugins for automatically inserting API data into the WooCommerce tables?
2. (Most likely situation) Does anybody have a good article or code snippet they can provide with examples of doing Insert, Update, and Delete functions using the WordPress framework with WooCommerce? It looks like the majority of the data might be stored in the wp_posts table, but I'm not sure exactly how to insert and pull Woo specific data out. I've already figured out which hook I want to use to trigger this integration, I just need to make the code do what it needs to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle,

`Woo/Lightspeed` user here, happy to report that `WooCommerce` released an official integration plugin last month (September 2015). I have not tried it, still reviewing documentation and need it to work with `WooCommerce` Bookings, but it looks promising: http://www.woothemes.com/2015/09/woocommerce-lightspeed-pos/

Answer (score 0):

There's this: https://github.com/solepixel/woocommerce-lightspeed-cloud ... looks like it's outdated though.